# Given two dates, find the number of christmas days on a weekday

Tags: python-3.x

Given two dates that are inputted by the user, it finds the number of chris in the given interval that are on weekdays so far what i thought of is:

```
import datetime
startmonth=int(input())
startday=int(input())
startyear=int(input())
endmonth=int(input())
endday=int(input())
endyear=int(input())
startdate=date(startyear,startmonth,startday)
enddate=date(endyear,endmonth,endday)

def Christmas(startyear,endyear):
cs=0
while startyear <= endyear:
    if (date(startyear, 12,25).weekday())<5:
        cs=cs+1
        startyear=startyear+1
    else:
        startyear=startyear+1
return cs
print("the total number of chirstmas days on a weekday is", Christmas(startyear,endyear))
```

but it just returns 0 no matter what the input. any suggestions/improvements for this?

Comment: That should probably be `return cs` in `Christmas` instead of `return bday` (which isn't defined anywhere anyway).

Comment: my bad! just changed some variables and forgot to change that. same problem still applies even when fixed

Answer (score 1):

You code identation is wrong.

```
def Christmas(startyear,endyear):
    cs=0
    while startyear <= endyear:
        if (date(startyear, 12,25).weekday())<5:
            cs=cs+1
            startyear=startyear+1
        else:
            startyear=startyear+1
    return cs

print(Christmas(2010, 2020)) # 8
```

Comment: still outputs 0, unfortunately.

Comment: Calling the function like Christmas(2010, 2020) gives me 8 as output. Are you getting 0 for the same function call?